# Crossdomain.xml file is not found when trying to access through https

Tags: https, unity-game-engine, crossdomain.xml

So my Unity game works perfect on the webplayer when I upload it to my hosting server if I access it non-secure but when I try to access it through https it loads the game fine & all but I get the error in game: Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found.

Any ideas why this is? Would greatly appreciate the help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the following XML as UTF-8.
2. Upload to root
3. Upload to game directory
4. In the editor, changed the editor setting for Security Emulation to website's domain.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <cross-domain-policy>
      <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
   </cross-domain-policy>
   ```

Comment: Do you need more info on this? or does this satisfy the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Also, if You try to access `crossdomain.xml` from `https`, probably `crossdomain.xml` must be on `https` too